# Why is this if statement broken in python?

Tags: python

I am attempting to make a 'simple' hangman game in python, but this if statement seems to not believe answer is == to guess, even when it clearly is... Thanks for any help :)

```
import random
guessed = False

file = open("hangmanwords.txt")
answer = file.readlines()[random.randint(0, 212)]
print(answer)


print("_ "*(len(answer)-1),"\n")

for counter in range(0,6):
  guess = input("Enter your guess:\n")
  if guess == answer:
    break
  else:
    print("Unlucky, try again")
    
if counter == 5:
  print("Unlucky, you did not guess it correctly. The correct word was",answer)
else:
  print("Well done, you got it!")
```

Comment: `print(repr(guess), repr(answer))` — Are they the same…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines returned by `readlines` end in a newline (except, potentially, the last line).

In your case, you don't want that. You can use `str.strip()` to remove whitespace (including newlines) from the beginning and end of a string.

You can also use `random.choice` to select a random word. Which is useful if you later want to add or remove words without changing the code!

Also, you don't need to hardcode the number of tries if you use the for-else construct.

```
import random

with open("hangmanwords.txt") as file:
    answer = random.choice([line.strip() for line in file if line and not line.isspace()])

print(answer)

print("_ " * len(answer))

for counter in range(6):
    guess = input("Enter your guess:\n")
    if guess == answer:
        print("Well done, you got it!")
        break
    else:
        print("Unlucky, try again")
else:    
    print("Unlucky, you did not guess it correctly. The correct word was", answer)
```